# PDF converted from EPS output directory

Tags: luatex, pdf, eps

How can I change the output directory of PDF figures converted from a EPS file? I have a output folder for my auxiliary files that are made on compile of the document, but figures in the format of EPS are leaving the output file of the PDF format in the same folder.

```
main.tex
img
- Figure.eps
- Figure.pdf
_output
- main.aux
- etc...
```

So to make it clear I want to move the file Figure.pdf to _output, not manually but so that the compiling software does it. I am using lualatex if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the `outdir` for `epstopdf` as well the usual `\graphicspath` (or `TEXINPUTS`) to find the original image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir = ./output/}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{demo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `epstopdf` is auto-loaded nowadays, but as we are explicitly setting a key it provides, I've gone with making it clear that it is loaded.